# Does Code::Blocks have a #define for its own version?

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I created a new project for wxWidgets in Code::Blocks and noticed that in the generated "about" window a "define" is used to show the wxWidgets version (wxVERSION_STRING).

I would like to show more information in the about window, including the version of C::B

Does C::B have a define to show its version?

One way to show the version of C::B from the linux command line:

```
codeblocks --script="nothing" 2>/dev/null | gawk -F'Code::Blocks ' '{ print $2 }' | gawk -F'- wx' '{ print $1 }'
```

The --script="nothing" option prevents C::B to start another instance.

Comment: are you trying to modify C::B? Did you talk to their developers about it? Keep in mind that it is only about IDE.

Comment: No I'm not trying to modify C::B, I just want to modify the about box in a generated new project. When wxWidgets is updated the new version is automatically set to the correct version when you compile the project. I would like to have something for C::B as well. For the time being I will just have "20.03" hardcoded in the source file. And "9.3.0" for GCC, also hardcoded.

Comment: well it definitely looks like you are trying to modify the C::B. Please check with its developers.

Comment: What is the use case here; why does your project's user need to know what version of Code::Blocks was used for compiling?

Comment: The user does not need it. It is something I want to know when users report an error.
I was hoping that C::B had a constant defined like wxWidgets has. The C::B IDE shows the version in its about screen. I have searched for such a constant in the IDE's source code but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Cant you just manually define it? Even if you have access to it, I assume then you will need to ship its necessary DLL's with your project which will be a huge drag.

Comment: @hennep, C::B is just an IDE. When the user reports a problem, it definitely is NOT connected to its version. Most likely it is a big in your program that needs to be fixed. Please understand what IDE is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Code::Blocks IDE doesn't provide the string constant you wanted, however it's easy to define this constant manually as a macro, and the IDE will automatically add this macro to all files it compiles.

BTW, if to run the `codeblocks` executable from the command line it'll output its version - however, I couldn't find this string in the Code::Blocks binary or configuration files - probably it's obfuscated.

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ codeblocks
Starting Code::Blocks Release 20.03  rev 11997 2020-04-18, 19:47:24 - wx3.0.4 - gcc 9.3.0 (Linux, unicode) - 64 bit
```

In order to define a macro `CB_VERSION` with value, equal to this string, you can open the `Global compiler settings` window, choose the `#defines` pane and enter this macro manually:

[image: GlobalCompilerSettings]

Please note the `"\\\"` string in the beginning and the `\\\""` string at the end of the macro value - without them the C++ preprocessor won't be able to pass the value of this macro into the C++ source code. So, the program below, compiled and linked **inside** the IDE, will output the value of the `CB_VERSION` macro.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char* ver = CB_VERSION;
  std::cout << ver << std::endl;
}
```

**UPDATE**. Another way to get information about your current Code::Blocks IDE is to look at the XML file `~/.config/codeblocks/default.conf`. This file contains a comment, which describes how and when the product has been built:

```
<!-- application info:
 svn_revision:  11997
 build_date:    2020-04-18, 19:47:24
 compiler_version:  gcc 9.3.0
 Linux Unicode
-->
```

Also the XML node `VERSION` in this file stores the official product version and release number:

```
<VERSION>
    <str>
        <![CDATA[20.03-r11997]]>
    </str>
</VERSION>
```

However, in order to extract these pieces of information you need to write some script and call it before the compilation - it's not easy. So, defining a macro with version information still looks better.

Comment: I've changed my first post and added a command line to extract the version info. But that is not going to work in Windows. Before I put that into a script, I have to find a way to do a similar thing in Windows. The two C::B versions (in Windows an Linux) can be different.

Comment: @hennep - sorry to say, I don't work in Windows. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

@hennep,

Neither you nor you project doesn't need to know the version of the IDE you use.

Even if you allow the user to compile your code - the user can choose to not to use C::B and just use a different IDE or don't use IDE at all.

As someone already wrote it - please understand what the IDE is.

TIA!!

Comment: Not someone, you did, and the repetition is getting annoying. I want to see it because there is never too much information when a program fails.

Comment: @hennep, please consider this - if I have a Code::Blocks version 18 and gcc version 9 and I report to you that I have a bug, but you have C::B version 18 and gcc version 7 and you says - I can't reproduce it - what will you do? One more time - C::B is just an IDE (integrated Development Environment) and any and all actual issues will be lying in the build system. IDE version is useless. Please learn what the IDE is , and what the compiler/linker is and then come back.

Comment: I had a problem with the Avrstudio IDE once. Version 4.18 worked perfectly and 4.19 had the tool chain messed up. The compiler in 4.19 worked without any problems most of the time. And both versions of the IDE used the same compiler. It would have saved a lot of time when I could have seen what version of the IDE was used to create the binary. I had to recompile every project that was created after 4.19 came out. In embedded code you do not waste space to store the version of all used tools but when I have plenty of space available, I want to store as much information as possible.